# how to get a list of users I have interacted with in a messaging system

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get a list of users that I have interacted with in a messaging system:

TABLE:

```
messages: id, sender_id, recipient_id, message, date
```

SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM `messages` 
WHERE 
(`sender_id` = :user_id OR `recipient_id` = :user_id)
GROUP BY `sender_id`, `recipient_id`
ORDER by `date` DESC
```

This gives me multiple rows with mismatched sender / recipient id's

I think its the `GROUP BY` thats causing it by not sure how to fix it

EDIT: I only need 1 row per interaction ( hence the `GROUP BY` )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GROUP BY` will combine all the rows with the same `sender_id` and `recipient_id`. Use a `UNION` to combine the two groups into one set of results:

```
SELECT correspondent, MAX(date) AS last_date
FROM (
    SELECT sender_id as correspondent, date
    FROM messages
    WHERE recipient_id = :user_id

    UNION ALL

    SELECT recipient_id as correspondent, date
    FROM messages
    WHERE send_id = :user_id) x
GROUP BY correspondent
ORDER BY last_date DESC
```

Comment: If you only want one row per interaction, how should it order by date? You want the most recent date of each interaction?

Comment: Yes, ordered by the date `DESC` along with the most recent message in that interaction

Comment: I tweaked your solution and am getting the right list of interactions but the messages in them are not the most recent SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT sender_id as 'c_id', message, date
    FROM messages
    WHERE recipient_id = :user_id

    UNION ALL

    SELECT recipient_id as 'c_id', message, date
    FROM messages
    WHERE send_id = :user_id) x GROUP BY c_id
ORDER BY date DESC

Comment: I've updated the answer to group the results and order by date.